# How to use "&" in Latex

Tags: latex

I tried a section heading with `\section{Project Aim & Objectives}` but in the document it shows as **Project Aim  Objectives**
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape with a backslash: `\&`